# Make expensive for loop multithreaded, Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, future, executorservice

I have a problem which I would like to solve using Java's `ExecutorService` and `Future` classes. I am currently taking many samples from a function that is very expensive for me to compute (each sample can take several minutes) using a for loop. I have a class `FunctionEvaluator` that evaluates this function for me and this class is quite expensive to instantiate, since it contains a lot of internal memory, so I have made this class easily reusable with some internal counters and a reset() method. So my current situation looks like this:

```
int numSamples = 100;
int amountOfData = 1000000;
double[] data = new double[amountOfData];//Data comes from somewhere...
double[] results = new double[numSamples];
//a lot of memory contained inside the FunctionEvaluator class,
//expensive to intialise
FunctionEvaluator fe = new FunctionEvaluator();

for(int i=0; i<numSamples; i++) {
    results[i] = fe.sampleAt(i, data);//very expensive computation
}
```

but I would like  to get some multithreading going to speed things up. It should be easy enough, because while each sample will share whatever is inside of `data`, it is a read-only operation and each sample is independent of any other. Now I wouldn't be having any trouble with this since I've used Java's `Future` and `ExecutorService` before, but never in a context where the `Callable` had to be re-used. So in general, how would I go about setting this scenario up given that I can afford to run `n` instantiations of `FunctionEvaluator`? Something (very roughly) like this:

```
int numSamples = 100;
int amountOfData = 1000000;
int N = 10;

double[] data = new double[amountOfData];//Data comes from somewhere...
double[] results = new double[numSamples];
//a lot of memory contained inside the FunctionEvaluator class,
//expensive to intialise
FunctionEvaluator[] fe = new FunctionEvaluator[N];

for(int i=0; i<numSamples; i++) {
    //Somehow add available FunctionEvaluators to an ExecutorService
    //so that N FunctionEvaluators can run in parallel. When a 
    //FunctionEvaluator is finished, reset then compute a new sample
    //until numSamples samples have been taken.
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks.

**EDIT**

So here is a toy example (which doesn't work :P). In this case the "expensive function" that I want to sample is just squaring an integer and the "expensive to instantiate class" that does it for me is called `CallableComputation`:

In TestConc.java:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestConc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SquareCalculator squareCalculator = new SquareCalculator();
        int numFunctionEvaluators = 2;
        int numSamples = 10;

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        CallableComputation c1 = new CallableComputation(2);
        CallableComputation c2 = new CallableComputation(3);

        CallableComputation[] callables = new CallableComputation[numFunctionEvaluators];
        Future<Integer>[] futures = (new Future[numFunctionEvaluators]);
        int[] results = new int[numSamples];

        for(int i=0; i<numFunctionEvaluators; i++) {
            callables[i] = new CallableComputation(i);
            futures[i] = executor.submit(callables[i]);
        }

        futures[0] = executor.submit(c1);
        futures[1] = executor.submit(c2);

        for(int i=numFunctionEvaluators; i<numSamples; ) {
            for(int j=0; j<futures.length; j++) {
                if(futures[j].isDone()) {
                    try {
                        results[i] = futures[j].get();
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    callables[j].set(i);
                    System.out.printf("Function evaluator %d given %d\n", j, i+1);
                    executor.submit(callables[j]);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("res%d=%d, ", i, results[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static boolean areDone(Future<Integer>[] futures) {
        for(int i=0; i<futures.length; i++) {
            if(!futures[i].isDone()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void printFutures(Future<Integer>[] futures) {
        for (int i=0; i<futures.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("f%d=%s | ", i, futures[i].isDone()?"done" : "not done");
        }System.out.printf("\n");
    }

}
```

In CallableComputation.java:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class CallableComputation implements Callable<Integer>{

    int input = 0;

    public CallableComputation(int input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void set(int i) {
        input = i;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        System.out.printf("currval=%d\n", input);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        return input * input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java8:

```
double[] result = IntStream.range(0, numSamples)
    .parallel()
    .mapToDouble(i->fe.sampleAt(i, data))
    .toArray();
```

The question asks how to execute heavy computational functions in parallel by loading as many CPU as possible.

Exert from the [Parallelism tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html):

> Parallel computing involves dividing a problem into subproblems,
>   solving those problems simultaneously (in parallel, with each
>   subproblem running in a separate thread), and then combining the
>   results of the solutions to the subproblems. Java SE provides the
>   fork/join framework, which enables you to more easily implement
>   parallel computing in your applications. However, with this framework,
>   you must specify how the problems are subdivided (partitioned). With
>   aggregate operations, the Java runtime performs this partitioning and
>   combining of solutions for you.

The actual solution includes:

- IntStream.range will generate the stream of integers from 0 to numSamples.
- [parallel()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) will split the stream and execute it will all available CPU on the box.
- [mapToDouble()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToDouble-java.util.function.Function-) will convert the stream of integers to the stream of doubles by applying the lamba expression that will do actual work.
- [toArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray--) is a terminal operation that will aggregate the result and return it as an array.

Comment: Thank you, Gray. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Right, this all makes sense to me now, but in what I actually currently do I need to call `fe.reset();` every time I call `fe.sample();` in order to reset the memory that the `fe` object contains, since I've found that it is too expensive to instantiate all that memory anew every time I want to take a sample. Remember, this is just a toy example where I want to see how a general for loop can be be parallelised, my actual function that I evaluate takes thousands of data points as the parameters, not just an integer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special code change required, you can use the same Callable again and again without any issue. Also, to improve efficiency, as you are saying, creating an instance of FunctionEvaluator is expensive, you can use only one instance and ensure that sampleAt is thread safe. One option is, maybe you can use all function local variables and don't modify any of the passing argument at any point of time while any of the thread is running

Please find a quick example below:

Code Snippet:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Callable<String> task1 = new Callable<String>(){public String call(){System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+"currentThread");return null;}}
executor.submit(task1);
executor.submit(task1);
executor.shutdown();
```

Please find the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I don't really see how that saves me the problem of using only a couple of instances. Because if I use only one instance and make it thread safe, I'm in the exact same situation of performing the computation serially. I guess the idea is to have N instantiations to take M>N samples. I've added a working example of what I want, maybe you can clarify using that? Thanks!

Comment: @MrSquid That depends upon how much piece of code will really cause the issue when executed in multithreaded environment. Moreover, The new piece of code is exactly what I am suggested you to do, apart from one thing as if why are you creating multiple instances of CallableComputation when same instance can be executed on multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each FunctionEvaluator's actual work as a Callable/Runnanle, then using a fixdThreadPool with a queue, then you just need to sumbit the target callable/runnable to the threadPool.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get some multithreading going to speed things up.

Sounds like a good idea but your code is massively over complex.  @Pavel has a dead simple Java 8 solution but even without Java 8 you can make it a lot easier.

All you need to do is to submit the jobs into the executor and then call `get()` on each one of the `Future`s that are returned.  A `Callable` class is not needed although it does make the code a lot cleaner.  But you certainly don't need the arrays which are a bad pattern anyway because a typo can easily generate out-of-bounds exceptions.  Stick to collections or Java 8 streams.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
List<Future<Integer>> futureList = new ArrayList<Future<Integer>>();
for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++ ) {
    // start the jobs running in the background
    futureList.add(executor.subject(new CallableComputation(i));
}
// shutdown executor if done submitting tasks, submitted jobs will keep running
executor.shutdown();
for (Future<Integer> future : futureList) {
    // this will wait for the future to finish, it also throws some exceptions
    Integer result = future.get();
    // add result to a collection or something here
}
```